# How to hide / do not display specific node fields by ip filtering in the Drupal 8 system

Tags: ip, field, filtering, record, drupal-8

I would like to have a solution for securing specific fields of specific nodes from being displayed in a given ip adress range in the Drupal 8 system. So far i haven't got any solution. I have found a module called "field_permission" but this module works by roles not by ip range.

If anyones knows a solution please let me know! 
Thank you!

Comment: I conceived how this could be working. My idea is to create different view modes (guest view and the full view for the users who are in a specific ip range). At the moment i dont know how to attach the view modes to different ip ranges. I know there is a Smart IP D8 module which can add a variable to the user session containing the user ip address. After this theres is a bult-in module, the Context module where you can create specific conditions when your specific action will be executed.

Comment: The problem there is not any chance to use ip address in it's condition part, and there is not an action to change the node view mode.